# Is it possible to visualize spatial errors?

Tags: data-visualization, error, spatial

I would like to ask if anyone is familiar with a way of visualizing the spatial error (lambda) produced by models such as the Spatial Error Model (SEM) or the Spatial Durbin Error Model (SDEM).

As far as a know, the standard routines for plotting spatial data, eg in R, are useful for visualizing variable values, but are of no use when attempting to depict an effect given the interaction of certain variables.

Thanks a lot.